# Function Declaration Issues Across Source Files in C++

Tags: c++, function, linker-errors

I'm working on a [Dice Project](http://github.com/lmwunder/Fishy-Dice) and haven't been able to figure out why the functions drawDice and rollDice are throwing me LNK 2019 errors when attempting to build my project. I'm trying to avoid posting a whole lot of code, but keep the context intact by writing a similar setup here below. I've modeled the function startGen in a similar manner that I have for the functions in my project.

Given the following code:

**fGenProto.hpp**

```cpp
#ifndef GEN_PROTO_HPP
#define GEN_PROTO_HPP

// Some Code
const int GENERATORS = 3;

void startGen( bool[], int );

#endif
```

**genFunct.cpp**

```cpp
#include "fGenProtos.hpp"

void startGen( runState[], genQuantity )
{
    for ( int iGenID = 0; iGenID < genQuantity; iGenID++ )
    {
        runState[iGenID] = true;
    }

}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "fGenProtos.hpp"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    bool genState[GENERATORS] = { false, false, false };

    for ( int iGenID = 0; iGenID < GENERATORS; iGenID++ )
    {
        cout << "Generator #" << iGenID << " Status: ";

        if ( genState[iGenID] )
            cout << "Online";

        else
            cout << "Stopped";
    }

    cout << "Starting Generators..." << endl;
    startGen( genState, GENERATORS );

    for ( int iGenID = 0; iGenID < GENERATORS; iGenID++ )
    {
        cout << "Generator #" << iGenID << " Status: ";

        if ( genState[iGenID] )
            cout << "Online";

        else
            cout << "Stopped";
    }
}
```

What would be the issue? And if the code above is perfect, I might as well modify this question or start a new question with links to the full code; I've been stumped for the last day or so on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
void startGen( runState[], genQuantity )
{
    for ( int iGenID = 0; iGenID < genQuantity; iGenID++ )
    {
        runState[iGenID] = true;
    }

}
```

is invalid. You should specify types of the parameters the same way as it is done in the function declaration.

```
void startGen( bool runState[], int genQuantity )
{
    for ( int iGenID = 0; iGenID < genQuantity; iGenID++ )
    {
        runState[iGenID] = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I looked in my source and I did have the same parameters for both, however, I did not do this for the example above.